# Dompdf doesn't have access to /tmp/log.htm

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I implemented the laraveldaily invoice package, but recently I've had issues generating PDFs and I get the following error:

```
[2021-07-16 21:46:31] .ERROR: file_put_contents(/tmp/log.htm): failed to open stream:
Permission denied {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): file_put_contents(/tmp/log.htm): 
failed to open stream: Permission denied at /path/to/my/laravel/project/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Dompdf.php:880)
```

[stacktrace]

So the first thing I did was I went into vendor and edited the following line in the Dompdf Options.php file:

```
 $this->setLogOutputFile('/path/to/my/laravel/directory/storage/logs/log.htm');
//        $this->setLogOutputFile($this->getTempDir() . "/log.htm");
```

This seems to work for when I run artisan commands, but Jobs still fail with the same error. So I have two questions:

1. Is there something that I need to run before my Jobs will start honoring this change?
2. How can I give Dompdf permissions to /tmp/log.htm?

Comment: Did you already find solution on this ?, I have same problem when running the jobs it always fails because of that permission.

Comment: Hi @jemz. One solution is to set pretty open permissions on your /tmp directory. It's not a sustainable solution though, and I'm still looking for an answer. Have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/402980/give-user-write-access-to-folder

Comment: Yeah that's what I did too it works now thank you